# Trying to modify a script to accept an array

Tags: arrays, image

I found a snowing image script on the web (http://www.jqueryrain.com/?GKBtfF4Q) and I am trying to modify the script to have multiple images.

So far, I figured out that it's necessary to change:

$(document).snow({ SnowImage: "snow.gif" });

to

$(document).snow({ SnowImage:[ "snow.gif", "2.gif", "3.gif", "4.gif"] });

but I am not sure how to make the script accept an array. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! (full disclosure: I am a coding noob)

Edit: pulled the script into JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/px6w1xdm/

function __ShowSnow(settings)
{

```
var snowsrc = settings.SnowImage;
var no = settings.Quantity;

var dx, xp, yp;    // coordinate and position variables
var am, stx, sty;  // amplitude and step variables
var i;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the loop (above var flake):

```
var randno = Math.floor(snowsrc.length*Math.random());
var randsnowsrc = snowsrc[randno];
```

Then change snowsrc to randsnowsrc in this line:

```
flake.append("<img src='" + randsnowsrc + "'>");
```